# What is the PIC micro controller naming scheme?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I've been dealing with the PIC micro controller for a while and as the question says I want to understand the naming scheme for each PIC line (8- 16- and 32-bit PIC).
For example what is the difference between 
PIC24FJ128GA010 and
PIC24FJ256GB110

and the numbers in pic32mx795f512l what do they mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some [18F nomenclature](http://www.sprut.de/electronic/pic/18f.htm#schuessel) but in German, so maybe use google translate?

All the PIC32's have a 'part number decoder page' for example page 328 "PRODUCT IDENTIFICATION SYSTEM" in [PIC32MX1XX/2XX](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001168F.pdf)

or page 656 "PRODUCT IDENTIFICATION SYSTEM" in [PIC32MZ Embedded Connectivity (EC) Family](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001191C.pdf)

AFAICT, all PIC datasheets have similar part-number-encode/decode pages. However, I'm only interested in PIC32.

Wikipedia [PIC microcontroller/Family core architectural differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller#Family_core_architectural_differences)

That divides the families by *instruction size*, and gives a useful summary of the 12bit, 14bit, enhanced 14bit, 16bit, 16bit dsPIC, PIC32 devices. Like many other microcontrollers, the 'natural' data size and instruction size can be different.

Edit:
I'm not a PIC24 person. Looking at the datasheets for [PIC24FJ256GB210](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39975a.pdf) and [PIC24FJ256GB110](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39897c.pdf), PIC24FJ256GB210 has 96kB RAM vs 16kB RAM for PIC24FJ256GB110

Typing the part numbers into "Search Microchip" at [Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/) usually gets to a brief summary of the part, and links to more information.

For example [PIC24FJ128GA010](http://www.microchip.com/search/searchapp/searchhome.aspx?id=2&q=PIC24FJ128GA010)

Typing the part numbers into "Search Data Sheets" at [Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/) will get to the device datasheet directly. Data Sheets usually has a summary of each family part on the first real page (page 3?). The table is often good enough to compare across similar families, and identify the differences.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thanks man!
I have a question if you are experienced in PIC24F
What is the difference between
PIC24FJ256GB110 and
PIC24FJ256GB210 ?

Comment: @3bdalla - I'm not a PIC24 person. Looking at the datasheets for [PIC24FJ256GB210](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39975a.pdf) and [PIC24FJ256GB110](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39897c.pdf),PIC24FJ256GB210 has 96kB RAM vs 16kB RAM for PIC24FJ256GB110

Answer (score 15):

It's really very simple and logical.

The PIC 10 has 6 pins, and the PIC 12 has 8 pins.  The PIC 16 uses the 14 bit instruction set, except when it uses the 12 bit instruction set, or when the model number is 4 digits starting with 1, then it uses the enhanced 14 bit instruction set.  The PIC 18 uses the 16 bit instruction set, and the dsPIC 30 the 24 bit instruction set.  The PIC 14 and 17 never existed (shhhh, don't tell anyone).  Now we have the PIC 24 and 32 which break the pattern, so you'll just have to remember those separately.  Oh, and there's a 33, but that's just a 30 that runs on 3.3 V.

See, simple, right?

Comment: You forgot the PIC12F's, which have 8 pins :) And PIC16F's use the extended instruction set when they have 4 additional digits.

Comment: @Wouter: Yes, good points.  I have updated my answer to include them.

Comment: Sounds like a sketch from the Two Ronnies ... ..

Answer (score 9):

- 8-bit PICs:

  - Baseline Architecture

    - PIC10
    - PIC12
    - PIC16
  - Mid-Range Architecture

    - PIC12
    - PIC16
  - Enhanced Mid-Range Architecture

    - PIC12F1xx
    - PIC16F1xx
  - PIC18F

    - PIC18 "J" Series
    - PIC18 "K" Series
- 16-bit PICs:

  - PIC24F - Lowest Power
  - PIC24H - Higher Performance
  - PIC24E - Highest Performance
  - dsPIC30F - 5V & EEPROM DSC
  - dsPIC33F - High Performance DSC
  - dsPIC33E - Highest Performance DSC
  - dsPIC33EV - 5V dsPIC33 "EV" Family DSC
  - dsPIC33CH - Dual Core DSC
- 32-bit PICs:

  - PIC32MK
  - PIC32MM - eXtreme Low Power (XLP)

    - PIC32MM GPL
    - PIC32MM GPM
  - PIC32MX

    - PIC32MX1/2 - eXtreme Low Power (XLP)
    - PIC32MX3/4
    - PIC32MX5/6/7 - Integrated Ethernet MAC
  - PIC32MZ - Embedded Connectivity (EC) Family

    - PIC32MZ1024 - 1 MB Flash
    - PIC32MZ2048 - 2 MB Flash
  - PIC32MZ EF - Highest performance
  - PIC32MZ DA - Integrated Graphics Acceleration & DRAM

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you see the update I made to the question ?

Comment: Regarding the PIC32MX795F512L - the '7' is one of the families of PIC32MX micros. The '512' indicates that the size of the program memory is 512 KB.

Answer (score 0):

For PIC24 i find in datasheet in PRODUCT IDENTIFICATION SYSTEM chapter.
More:
http://www.microchip.com/forums/m718722.aspx